# Rails runner not sending mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to send mail using the rails runner CLI command like so:

```
rails runner -e development ReminderMailer.send_mail
```

app/mailers/reminder_mailer.rb :

```
class ReminderMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "other_email@gmail.com"

  def send_mail()
    @message = "hello world!"
    @foo = mail(to: "my_email@gmail.com", subject: "Reminder")

    puts @foo.to_s
    puts "Everything worked"

  end

end
```

My puts are getting printed to the console showing "Everything worked" , but the mail is not being sent.  I have `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true` in my config/environments/development.rb file and when I run the `send_mail()` function from within a controller in my app it works, and the mail is delivered.

It only doesn't work from the command prompt.  Why could this be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call a `deliver` on the mail object for it to get sent. Try changing  the line to

```
@foo = mail(to: "my_email@gmail.com", subject: "Reminder").deliver
```

Although how it is working from your controllers is a bit confusing. Not to mention, how can he successfully call an instance method on class? Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: This was it.. the controller had a .deliver call while the mailer did not.  I thank you profusely.